# Automatic add/load raster layer within selected polygon

Tags: raster, grids-graticules, model

Is it possible to automatic load/add georeferenced raster by selecting a polygon in a grid or by making a selection in a map. Perhaps it is possible to make at tool with modelbuilding?

Comment: What software are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: I use qgis. At the moment i have not tried anything. I have a lot of Geotiffs local on my pc. I want to be able to select an area of interest and then automaticly load geotiff for that certain area. i havent tried anything because i really dont know how to solve this. I do have access to arcmap if it helps.